# Use the "FIND" formula to find a case different from a given caracter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I just started using a "FIND" formula with Array:

```
=MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A3&"0123456789"))
```

Or something similar for letters

```
=MIN(FIND({"A";"B"};A4&"AB"))
```

I am now wondering if there is a way to use "FIND" to find the first case different from a given character. 
For Example in the string: "AAABABBBAABBAAXPLE"
I would like to find the first character different from "A".   (result should be 4 in the example) 
Or with array: different from "A" and from "B" (result should be 15 in the example)

Comment: you can use countif function to find the character

Comment: @NoobProgrammer I am trying to find in one cell, the position of NOT "A", I don't think Countif can help here?

Comment: oh sure then try something like this =LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"a",""))

Comment: @NoobProgrammer, Good idea, but it doesn t work in the example, as the letter A is not only at the beginning.

Comment: not quite sure about that but i definitely can upvote your post to raise more attention. Hopefully some pros can help you :D

Comment: @pnuts doesn t work in my example (it returns the position of the latest ("B"), but if "A" comes after again it stops searching

Comment: @pnuts, the first result different from "A" or "B" is "X" in the example, so I want to find 15 as result in this example

Comment: yes but I meant it generally. Either with an array like yours to find the position of not A and not B. or without array just the position of not A ( I edited the question to show the expected result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For excluding two letters try

`=FIND(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"A",""),"B","")),A1)`

This is case-sensitive

or you can adapt this formula to exclude any list of numbers/letters

`=MATCH(1,INDEX(ISNA(MATCH(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),{"A","B"},0))+0,0),0)`

.....but this isn't case-sensitive

Comment: It works perfectly but I don't see the point of the "LEFT" in the first formula

Comment: For your example "AAABABBBAABBAAXPLE" in the first formula the two SUBSTITUTE functions remove all the "A"s and "B"s leaving just "XPLE", so the formula uses LEFT to take the leftmost character of that, i.e. "X" and then FIND finds the position of the first "X" within A1, which is the position of the first non "A"/"B" value

Comment: OK taking LEFT out only worked in my example because there is no A or B in the end "XPLE"